# GestureProblem: method not disable its calling next view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using swap gesture its working fine in a view (Ex class A) but its call in another viewController (Ex - Class B, C). I'm not using navigationController simply addView on view..
Code -

```
swipeLeftRecognizer                             = nil;
swipeLeftRecognizer                             = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
swipeLeftRecognizer.direction                   = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
swipeLeftRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired     = 1;
swipeLeftRecognizer.delegate                    = self;
     swipeLeftRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView   = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftRecognizer];

swipeRightRecognizer                            = nil;
swipeRightRecognizer                            = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
swipeRightRecognizer.direction                  = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
swipeRightRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired    = 1;
swipeRightRecognizer.delegate                   = self;

 swipeRightRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView        = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightRecognizer];
```

Due to this i'm not enable give the action of Button in another view (B, C). Please tell me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set `UserInteractionEnabled = NO`, on view where you don't want to receive user actions when other views are visible. And when you remove other views again enable.